# posrgresql/mysql:extract data to add on an original file incrementally in linux?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

how to select data from posrgresql/mysql to add on an original file/csv in linux?

original file/csv:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| a    |    1 | A    |
| b    |    2 | B    |
| c    |    3 | C    |
+------+------+------+
```

select * from tableA;

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| d    |    4 | D    |
+------+------+------+
```

add on the selected rows on file/csv:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| a    |    1 | A    |
| b    |    2 | B    |
| c    |    3 | C    |
| d    |    4 | D    |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: You want to append data using mysql or postgresl or both?

Comment: anyone of them is well,but better is using postgresql @KKK